# Debezium Source connector cannot create Apache Kafka topics in ksqldb

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb, debezium

I am new in PostgreSQL and Apache Kafka/Confluent Community Edition.
I would like to do some ETL tasks via ksqldb-server /read source data from PostgreSQL and load into MySQL/ via Debezium Source Connector.

All services running via docker-compose file

```
---
version: '3'
services:
# ------------------------------
# ZOOKEEPER 
# ------------------------------
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.0.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

# ------------------------------
# BROKER 
# ------------------------------
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.0.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

# ------------------------------
# SCHEMA-REGISTRY 
# ------------------------------
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.0.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - broker
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

# ------------------------------
# CONNECT 
# ------------------------------
  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.0-6.2.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    volumes:
      - "/home/csivk/Desktop/ETL/:/home/appuser/ETL/"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      #CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      #CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      #CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      #CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.0.0.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
    command:
       - bash
       - -c
       - | 
         echo "Installing connector plugins"
         confluent-hub install --no-prompt streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse:2.4.0
         confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-mqtt:1.5.1
         confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:latest
         confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql:1.7.1
         #
         echo "Downloading JDBC drivers"
         cd /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc/
         curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.27/mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar -o mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar
         #
         echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
         /etc/confluent/docker/run &
         #
         # Dont Exit
         sleep infinity

# ------------------------------
# CONTROL-CENTER 
# ------------------------------        
  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.0.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

# ------------------------------
# ksqldb-server 
# ------------------------------
  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.0.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'

# ------------------------------
# ksqldb-cli 
# ------------------------------
  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:7.0.0
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

# ------------------------------
# ksql-datagen 
# ------------------------------
  ksql-datagen:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:7.0.0
    hostname: ksql-datagen
    container_name: ksql-datagen
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - ksqldb-server
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... && \
                       cub kafka-ready -b broker:29092 1 40 && \
                       echo Waiting for Confluent Schema Registry to be ready... && \
                       cub sr-ready schema-registry 8081 40 && \
                       echo Waiting a few seconds for topic creation to finish... && \
                       sleep 11 && \
                       tail -f /dev/null'"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST: schema-registry
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT: 8081

# ------------------------------
# Rest-Proxy 
# ------------------------------
  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.0.0
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      
# ------------------------------
# MySQL 
# ------------------------------
  db-mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - ./dbscripts/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    restart: on-failure
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: kafka
      MYSQL_USER: kafka
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: kafka

# ------------------------------
# PostgreSQL 
# ------------------------------
  db-postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    hostname: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
      - ./dbscripts/postgres:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
#    user: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: kafka
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: kafka
    command:
      - "postgres"
      - "-c"
      - "wal_level=logical"
#      - "wal_level=replica"
#      - "max_wal_senders=1"
#      - "max_replication_slots=1"
      
# ------------------------------
# Adminer 
# ------------------------------  
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    volumes:
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
      - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    hostname: adminer
    container_name: adminer
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
# ------------------------------
# MQTT 
# ------------------------------
  mqtt:
    container_name: mqtt
    hostname: mosquitto
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:latest
    volumes:
      - ./mosquitto_settings/config:/mosquitto/config/:ro
      - ./mosquitto_settings/data:/mosquitto/data/
      - ./mosquitto_settings/log:/mosquitto/log/
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
      - 9001:1883
    restart: on-failure
    network_mode: host
```

but when i create source connector - the source connector is running but the topic is not created. I dont know why .. I read a lot of discussion but there were no answers to my issue. Could somebody help me with this?

Thank a lot

This is my Source connector configuration from ksqldb-server

```
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR `SR-PG-Debezium` WITH(
 "connector.class"             = 'io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector',
 "plugin.name"                 = 'pgoutput',
 "database.hostname"               = '192.168.219.152', 
 "database.port"               = '5432', 
 "database.user"               = 'kafka', 
 "database.password"               = 'password', 
 "database.dbname"                 = 'kafka', 
 "database.server.name"            = 'postgres', 
 "table.include.list"              = 'kafka.mqtt_table',
 "topic.creation.enable"           = 'true',
 "topic.creation.default.replication.factor"   = '1',  
 "topic.creation.default.partitions"       = '10',  
 "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy"   = 'compact',  
 "topic.creation.default.compression.type" = 'lz4');
```

Comment: I'm asking out of curiosity, what will be the topic's name? shouldn't a `topics` or `topic.creation.default.include` configuration be there?

Comment: As I understand correctly the topic name will be created automatically based on db, table name... or am I understand it not correctly?

Comment: Since I haven't used docker or PostgresConnector, I can't say anything exactly. But for my case, `"topics": "topic_name", "auto.create": "true"` lines allows my connector to create a new topic, if it doesn't exist. It's for a jdbc connector but you may give it a try

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it not helped